# RadioButtonList FindByValue Problems

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, radiobuttonlist

I seem to be having problems with finding a specific value in a radio button list.

So if I have Radio Button List like this;

```
[ID]  [Value]
 1    Apple
 2    Orange
 3    Pear
 4    Banana
```

I want to use vb.net code behind to see if an item exists. So I thought I could do this;

```
Dim v as Integer = 3
if rdoTheTest.Items.FindByValue(v) = True Then Msgbox("I Found you")
```

Problem is I get "Operator = is not defined for types ListItem and integer", am I using this correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change your code like

```
Dim v as Integer = 3
if rdoTheTest.Items.FindByValue(v) IsNot Nothing Then Msgbox("I Found you")
```